# Play Audio using jQuery

Tags: jquery, html

I have a list of Sound Icon images in different divs on my website. I'm trying to use jQuery to play/pause different songs on `mouseenter` and `mouseleave` dependent on which icon is hovered over. I have the first item working but am having problems understanding the best way to get the rest working.  Any help with this would be really appreciated. Thanks.

```
<audio preload="auto" id="songOne">
  <source src="audio/****.mp3" controls></source>
  <source src="audio/****.ogg" controls></source>
  <source src="audio/****.wav" controls></source>
  Your browser isn't invited for super fun audio time.
</audio>

$(document).ready(function(){
  var song1 = $("#songOne")[0];
  $(".topDownloads img").first().mouseenter(function() {
    song1.play();
    $(".topDownloads img").mouseleave(function() {
      song1.pause();
    });
  });
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you might be able to do is embed the specific song object name onto the element which the user is clicking. For example, assuming the `.topDownloads` element is a div:

```
<div class="topDownloads">
  <img data-song="someSong" src="..." />
  <img data-song="anotherSong" src="..." />
</div>
```

You can now use that data attribute in your mouse event callback. Store all your song objects in a key->value object and retrieve them from the data attribute.

```
// setting up key->value song pairs
var songs = {
  'someSong':$("#someSong")[0],
  'anotherSong':$("#anotherSong")[0],
};

$(".topDownloads img").hover(function() {
   // extract song key name
   var songItem = songs[$(this).data('song')];
   songItem.play();
},function() {
   // extract song key name
   var songItem = songs[$(this).data('song')];
   songItem.pause();
});
```

Notice that I've used the [`.hover()` function instead](http://api.jquery.com/hover/) of `.mouseenter()` and `.mouseleave()`. This function receives two functions as parameters, the first function is triggered when the mouse enters the element, and the second function executes when the mouse leaves the element. I think this syntax is a bit easier to work with and makes more sense.

Comment: Hi Lix, thanks so much for the quick reply. I'm pretty new  to this, so at the risk of sounding stupid, could you explain the 'data-song' attribute on the 'img' tag,(i.e is this a source or simply an id or something else entirely). Thanks again for your help, its much appreciated. BTW thanks for the tip with the .hover() function, makes a lot more sense, Thanks again.

Comment: Great! Yea - sorry that I didn't get back to you on your last comment, but I'm glad to hear that you sorted it out! Happy coding!